# Setting my TextBox Text value isn't doing anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, events

In my webform I have a few textboxes. I've got an event handler for one of my web user controls. When the event is fired, I set the textbox value but nothing happens.

It doesn't look like the page is posting back (does it have something to do with my web user control in a modal popup?) which I assume is the problem...

Am I doing something wrong?

Webform Event Handler:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchCompanies1.CompanyFound += new WebParts_SearchCompanies.CompanyFoundEventHandler(SearchCompanies1_CompanyFound);
}

void SearchCompanies1_CompanyFound(Company company)
    {
        myTextBox.Text = company.Name;
        popup.Hide();

    }
```

Modal popup and panel:

```
 <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup" runat="server" DropShadow="true"
    TargetControlID="lnkSearchEditCompany" PopupControlID="pnlSearch"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackgroundSearchCompany" CancelControlID="lnkCancel">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
     <asp:Panel ID="pnlSearch" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupSearchCompany" style ="display:none">
        <table width = "100%" cellpadding = "0" cellspacing = "0">
            <tr>
                <td align = "right">
                    <strong><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text = "[X]"></asp:LinkButton></strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <uc2:SearchCompanies ID="SearchCompanies1" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

My events are definitely being fired and handled. I have an update panel and update progress on the web user control.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that after removing my UpdatePanel, it worked. I tried setting the UpdateMode to both "Always" and "Conditional" but to no avail.

This isn't a solution, but it's a workaround for anyone who's got the same problem until I figure out what I'm doing wrong. Let me know if anyone figures it out please.